# How to write a multithreaded function for processing different tasks concurrently?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, concurrency, arguments

I would like to define a `do_in_parallel` function in python that will take in functions with arguments, make a thread for each and perform them in parallel. The function should work as so:

```
do_in_parallel(_sleep(3), _sleep(8), _sleep(3))
```

I am however having a hard time defining the `do_in_parallel` function to take multiple functions with multiple arguments each, here's my attempt:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def do_in_parallel(*kwargs):

    tasks = []

    for func in kwargs.keys():
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(arg for arg in kwargs[func]))
        t.start()
        tasks.append(t)

    for task in tasks:        
        task.join()

def _sleep(n):
    sleep(n)
    print('slept', n)
```

Using it as so, and getting the following error:

```
do_in_parallel(_sleep=3, _sleep=8, _sleep=3)

>> do_in_parallel(sleepX=3, sleepX=8, sleepX=3)
                            ^
>> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Can someone explain what I would need to change in my function so that it can take multiple function parameters as so:

```
do_in_parallel(_sleep(3), _sleep(8), maybe_do_something(else, and_else))
```

Comment: @VineethSai  hmmm... only if I take the args part out of th thread, but then it's not doing them in parallel

Comment: Use `list` instead of `**kwargs**`, beside this **one** `for <args>` is enough.

Comment: @stovfl what do you mean ' beside this one for <args> is enough'

Comment: You are doing `for func in kwargs.keys():`, and inside `for arg in kwargs[func]`. Change to `args=kwargs[func]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `do_in_parallel(_sleep(3), _sleep(8), maybe_do_something(else, and_else))`

This call structure wouldn't work anyway since you are passing the results of your target functions to `do_in_parallel` (you are already calling _sleep etc.).

What you need to do instead, is bundle up **tasks** and pass these tasks to your processing function. A task here is a tuple, containing the target function to be called and an argument-tuple `task = (_sleep, (n,))`.

I suggest you then use a ThreadPool and the `apply_async` method to process the separate tasks.

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # .dummy.Pool is a ThreadPool


def _sleep(n):
    sleep(n)
    result = f'slept {n}'
    print(result)
    return result


def _add(a, b):
    result = a + b
    print(result)
    return result


def do_threaded(tasks):
    with Pool(len(tasks)) as pool:
        results = [pool.apply_async(*t) for t in tasks]
        results = [res.get() for res in results]
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    tasks = [(_sleep, (i,)) for i in [3, 8, 3]]
    # [(<function _sleep at 0x7f035f844ea0>, (3,)),
    #  (<function _sleep at 0x7f035f844ea0>, (8,)),
    #  (<function _sleep at 0x7f035f844ea0>, (3,))]
    tasks += [(_add, (a, b)) for a, b in zip(range(0, 3), range(10, 13))]

    print(do_threaded(tasks))
```

Output:

```
10
12
14
slept 3
slept 3
slept 8
['slept 3', 'slept 8', 'slept 3', 10, 12, 14]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: just making sure,  "from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool " this is multithreading although it's from the multiprocessing package?

Comment: @callmeGuy exactly. it's "dummy" because it uses threads instead of processes but otherwise offers the same methods. It's a wrapper for `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, you could directly import the latter if you prefer.

Comment: that's cool, thanks. Do you reckon I can add functions that read and write to and from pandas df? Like will I need any locks?

Comment: @callmeGuy If you would need locks to keep data consistent depends on what you are doing exactly, that's not a question one could answer for the general case. If you think about this keep in mind, that a thread can be interrupted at any time while performing non-atomic operations. So you would need locks in cases where you need transactions to be non-interruptible.